# HEVC Fairplay stream

Tags: avfoundation, hevc, fairplay, shaka, zencoder

I am trying to create an HEVC Fairplay stream. I have tried using Shaka Packager,Bento4 and Zencoder. But with no luck.

Has anybody created a HEVC Fairplay stream? 
If yes, then how?

Answer (score 1):

This should work with Bento4. For HEVC video, you should use the fragmented MP4 flavor of HLS for your stream, which you can do by using Bento4's `mp4dash` command and the `--hls` option. 
You can reach out on the Bento4 GitHub page if you need more help, I can followup with you there.

Comment: I used this command for stream creation : "python2 mp4-dash.py --hls --fairplay-key-uri="skd://one?cek=ca864f218fa006bb7e59a35e110551e4&iv=890fb300266e05646dd3e37aa9e42967" --encryption-cenc-scheme=cbcs --encryption-key=ca864f218fa006bb7e59a35e110551e4:ca864f218fa006bb7e59a35e110551e4:890fb300266e05646dd3e37aa9e42967 frag_video.mp4" but nothing plays